# WordPress Multisite - Questions about select all posts from all network sites

Tags: multisite

Someone would tell me how i could do so that all posts published on the websites of my network were published on the main site of the network also?

Or more directly, any way of doing a select on which he select all posts of all prefixes wp_2_posts, wp_3_posts infinitely...

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through all sites of the network, we need a function like this (it's an adaptation, check the original that's linked there too):

[Hierarchical Page Listing of all Pages in a Multisite Network](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/114217)

And when doing the loop, you will `switch_to_blog($id)` and perform any normal read/write operation. Here's an example of post insertion after a site creation:

[WP_INSERT_POST issue on Wordpress Multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/115724)

And [here's an experimental plugin](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/7036415) I did to publish a post from one site to another. It displays a meta box when editing a post where you can select other site where the same post is to be published. I guess it's a good starting point to develop a custom solution.